# Bokeh Slider custom JS callback

Tags: python, pandas, callback, slider, bokeh

I am new to Bokeh and trying to implement a Slider callback using CustomJS. I have my sales data grouped by years, months, days. Based on the slider value(1-12), my monthly data has to be changed on the plot. Below is my code for this:
Slider values(0-12)- Months numbers
X-axis: Days(1-30)
y-axis:Sales

```
df3=df


df3['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Inv Date'])
df3.set_index('Date2', inplace=True)


df3['month'] = df3.index.month
df3['year'] = df3.index.year
df3['day'] = df3.index.day

df3['Dateday'] = pd.to_datetime(df3[['year','month', 'day']])

source1=df3.groupby(['year','month','day'], as_index = False).sum()

current_month=ColumnDataSource(source1[source1['year']== dt.now().year])


hover3 = HoverTool(
        tooltips = [
            ('day', '@day'),
            ('Sales','@{Sales}{0,0}'),
            ],
        formatters = {
            'day': 'datetime',
            'Sales': 'numeral'}
       )

 p =  figure(
 title='YEARLY SALES',  
 plot_width=600, 
 plot_height=400, 
 min_border=3,

tools = [hover3,'box_zoom','wheel_zoom', 'pan','reset'],  
toolbar_location="above")
p.vbar(x='day', top='Sales', width=0.2, color='#e8bc76', 
source=current_month)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Day'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'normal'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '12pt'
p.yaxis[0].formatter = NumeralTickFormatter(format="0,0")




callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=current_month), code="""       
        var f = slider.get('value');
        var data = source.data; 

        data1=current_month[current_month['month']== f]
        day=data1[data1['day']]
        Sales=data1[data1['Sales']]
source.trigger('change');
    """)
slider = Slider(start=1, end=12, value=1, step=1, title="power",             
callback=callback)

layout = column(slider, p)

show(layout)
```

Can anyone please help me out. I am stuck here on filtering my dataframes based on the Custom Callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fairly quick if you want to use `bokeh serve`, which can call native python callback functions. This is also possible using javascript callback `CustomJS` as well.

Since I don't have your data, I have generated a dummy data using following code -

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'base' : ["2017-01-01" for t in range(10000)],
    'Date' : [random.randint(0, 1035) for t in range(10000)], 
                   'Sales' : [random.random() for t in range(10000)]})
df['base'] = pd.to_datetime(df['base'])
df["Date2"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["base"] + timedelta(days=x['Date']), axis=1)
df.drop(['base', 'Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

This will give 10000 Rows of random sales between 2017 to 2019. In the example below, I have filtered only for 2017.

In the next step, I will generate two `ColumnDataSource` - one for all 2017 data, and one for only month 1, 2017 data - to create initial graph. The second one will be used to generate `vbar`

```
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models import Slider, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.models.ranges import FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, IndexFilter, BooleanFilter, HoverTool

df.set_index('Date2', inplace=True)
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['day'] = df.index.day
source1=df.groupby(['year','month','day'], as_index = False).sum()
source = source1[source1['year']== 2017]
sourcex = source[source['month'] ==1]
Overall=ColumnDataSource(source)
Curr=ColumnDataSource(sourcex)
boolinit = source['month']==1
view = CDSView(source=Overall, filters=[BooleanFilter(boolinit)])
hover3 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('day', '@day'),('Sales','@{Sales}{0,0}')],
                   formatters = {'day': 'datetime','Sales': 'numeral'})

p =  figure(title='YEARLY SALES',  plot_width=600, plot_height=400, min_border=3,
tools = [hover3,'box_zoom','wheel_zoom', 'pan','reset'],  
toolbar_location="above")

r = p.vbar(x='day', top='Sales', width=0.2, color='#e8bc76', source=Curr)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Day'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'normal'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '12pt'
```

Now, we will write the javascript callback function, it will change the `ColumnDataSource` used in `vbar` by applying filter on the overall `ColumnDataSource`. Add this to slider callback, and we have a javascript based data filter -

```
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=Overall, sc=Curr), code="""       
        var f = slider.value;
        sc.data['x'] = [];
        sc.data['top'] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= source.get_length(); i++){
          if (source.data['month'][i] == f){
            sc.data['day'].push(source.data['day'][i])
            sc.data['Sales'].push(source.data['Sales'][i])
          }
        }
        sc.change.emit();
    """)
slider = Slider(start=1, end=12, value=1, step=1, title="Month", callback=callback)
callback.args["slider"] = slider

layout = column(slider, p)

output_file("Filterdata.html")
#fig.view.filters[0].booleans = indices
show(layout)
```

This will generate the HTML of following type -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bokeh Plot</title>
        
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.16.min.css" type="text/css" />
        
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.12.16.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-widgets-0.12.16.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="bk-root">
            <div class="bk-plotdiv" id="1b4d2791-052d-4f87-b697-2703d126d006"></div>
        </div>
        
        <script type="application/json" id="59b3ceeb-f6e4-457f-8243-236ad4e4ecc6">
          {"6e250d5c-2f75-4d15-9ea7-19bd720babe3":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"callback":null,"formatters":{"Sales":"numeral","day":"datetime"},"renderers":"auto","tooltips":[["day","@day"],["Sales","@{Sales}{0,0}"]]},"id":"07bbdbc1-b49b-4f0e-a9b7-214f33f39250","type":"HoverTool"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"554a6885-1e34-4138-80c0-2dbb98325bc3","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"children":[{"id":"e8e7c404-9a9e-4a03-bdd4-3f0bcd5dc234","type":"WidgetBox"},{"id":"afe8da60-9dbb-4cea-958f-247636333a7c","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"}]},"id":"0a97fc7d-20ab-49fa-b18f-ca63fdc4d277","type":"Column"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Day","axis_label_text_font_size":{"value":"12pt"},"axis_label_text_font_style":"normal","formatter":{"id":"1909b1bd-0493-46ce-a5f6-b7dbdc4853c3","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"afe8da60-9dbb-4cea-958f-247636333a7c","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"238e4175-dd46-4884-b52d-12443011009a","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"7e35e0a2-4439-4e0e-a3c1-47fbd9e6fa37","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"19bf27b3-a519-4d20-ae4b-1228506e8c65","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"afe8da60-9dbb-4cea-958f-247636333a7c","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"2ee2fcc2-f073-43b3-9aca-2ee8c03357fa","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"e9dd9ab8-79fd-43f3-96a0-3a8b0e833438","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"fe1ac751-02a0-4545-89ff-87dbe314a34f","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"aa4dd815-46f2-42c9-9b8a-1779434e9afc","type":"VBar"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"25d28579-4ce2-4d3e-8946-c6e0500c573c","type":"VBar"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"c32a4aeb-a7a3-4130-a0e0-af65a56efacf","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"552417f6-d44d-4004-8d17-81b1e4b05e7b","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"children":[{"id":"eb513edf-4b54-4590-9b7b-d4cc1f60420c","type":"Slider"}]},"id":"e8e7c404-9a9e-4a03-bdd4-3f0bcd5dc234","type":"WidgetBox"},{"attributes":{},"id":"bcfbd38a-8abf-4a13-a5e2-61ebfe5004a1","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"b3d136e0-d5f7-4255-9038-d25e07847ec2","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1909b1bd-0493-46ce-a5f6-b7dbdc4853c3","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"7e35e0a2-4439-4e0e-a3c1-47fbd9e6fa37","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"e9dd9ab8-79fd-43f3-96a0-3a8b0e833438","type":"LinearAxis"}],"min_border":3,"plot_height":400,"renderers":[{"id":"7e35e0a2-4439-4e0e-a3c1-47fbd9e6fa37","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"bafbac35-977e-4aff-9a7f-794ec9b01659","type":"Grid"},{"id":"e9dd9ab8-79fd-43f3-96a0-3a8b0e833438","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"c72d4b3e-b711-4ba8-a197-82ad4457ed7e","type":"Grid"},{"id":"554a6885-1e34-4138-80c0-2dbb98325bc3","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"552417f6-d44d-4004-8d17-81b1e4b05e7b","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"f6ba763a-1582-4691-8c88-658157e6752c","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"95b4b9e2-94be-4be2-9761-be749c59ae45","type":"Toolbar"},"toolbar_location":"above","x_range":{"id":"c3a3bd50-523c-4fb1-b623-179318de5821","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"366a8395-e407-44d6-9740-75995f462aa6","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"b3d136e0-d5f7-4255-9038-d25e07847ec2","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"61100931-0c81-49dd-b38e-b0ba2ad2b715","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"afe8da60-9dbb-4cea-958f-247636333a7c","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"c3a3bd50-523c-4fb1-b623-179318de5821","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"19bf27b3-a519-4d20-ae4b-1228506e8c65","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"f6af654a-341d-45a8-a1a4-c2d17e5ea072","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"554a6885-1e34-4138-80c0-2dbb98325bc3","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"8bd715e6-c00a-4a79-b615-697fac1cb0ff","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"238e4175-dd46-4884-b52d-12443011009a","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"afe8da60-9dbb-4cea-958f-247636333a7c","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"2ee2fcc2-f073-43b3-9aca-2ee8c03357fa","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"c72d4b3e-b711-4ba8-a197-82ad4457ed7e","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"Sales":{"__ndarray__":"8NQrVcgzF0BmMWa9ZFEJQI0Nm+l22BFAkpu8wBOxG0CFf2FD7okNQKqmXZOEDhlAwIGsfto5FkBnl1JfhlwQQFbqcDGFTRJAr0Xiczd5IkDSpmZHOyURQNRIWMMZqwVA4DSUAzIkHkDly04nIZsJQAxQHPiCBwpA9bjTr6g0GUBlCMyBLaMdQI0PreXoOQVADFRAxvEIFkAcwvjsW4UPQFBni1oUUxhAJzhcwTr6GkD73ROYc0ERQIIKgPW5OglAjuGAQmxwFkBMPcUNQeEVQGD60x1g+RZAAuog6+lOFEAtXcdh1csRQGrJzOkK3A5ATOF2Rs3rGUA=","dtype":"float64","shape":[31]},"day":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31],"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30],"month":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],"year":[2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017]},"selected":{"id":"b457b820-5485-4b7a-9872-3c44fad0cd7a","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"3b7b5e0f-6ed6-43f4-af7c-f949bf6641b9","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"fe1ac751-02a0-4545-89ff-87dbe314a34f","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"3b7b5e0f-6ed6-43f4-af7c-f949bf6641b9","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"366a8395-e407-44d6-9740-75995f462aa6","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"b457b820-5485-4b7a-9872-3c44fad0cd7a","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"args":{"sc":{"id":"fe1ac751-02a0-4545-89ff-87dbe314a34f","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"slider":{"id":"eb513edf-4b54-4590-9b7b-d4cc1f60420c","type":"Slider"},"source":{"id":"b605ddc1-1408-4956-864f-c602df6f550a","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"code":"       \n        var f = slider.value;\n        sc.data['x'] = [];\n        sc.data['top'] = [];\n        for (var i = 0; i &lt;= source.get_length(); i++){\n          if (source.data['month'][i] == f){\n            sc.data['x'].push(source.data['day'][i])\n            sc.data['top'].push(source.data['Sales'][i])\n          }\n        }\n        sc.change.emit();\n    "},"id":"46a732ae-b9c4-4617-b4fe-831f344608ec","type":"CustomJS"},{"attributes":{},"id":"0f4916a7-aa28-4cdb-839e-f4de9080462d","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"07bbdbc1-b49b-4f0e-a9b7-214f33f39250","type":"HoverTool"},{"id":"8bd715e6-c00a-4a79-b615-697fac1cb0ff","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"0f4916a7-aa28-4cdb-839e-f4de9080462d","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"bcfbd38a-8abf-4a13-a5e2-61ebfe5004a1","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"14f7d7d3-d67b-4d72-a86d-6a1d7b5dcc7d","type":"ResetTool"}]},"id":"95b4b9e2-94be-4be2-9761-be749c59ae45","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"14f7d7d3-d67b-4d72-a86d-6a1d7b5dcc7d","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"2ee2fcc2-f073-43b3-9aca-2ee8c03357fa","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"#e8bc76"},"line_color":{"value":"#e8bc76"},"top":{"field":"Sales"},"width":{"value":0.2},"x":{"field":"day"}},"id":"aa4dd815-46f2-42c9-9b8a-1779434e9afc","type":"VBar"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"fe1ac751-02a0-4545-89ff-87dbe314a34f","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"c32a4aeb-a7a3-4130-a0e0-af65a56efacf","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"afe8da60-9dbb-4cea-958f-247636333a7c","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"238e4175-dd46-4884-b52d-12443011009a","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"bafbac35-977e-4aff-9a7f-794ec9b01659","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"Sales":{"__ndarray__":"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","dtype":"float64","shape":[365]},"day":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31],"index":[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,243,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,310,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,364],"month":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12],"year":[2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017,2017]},"selected":{"id":"f24d2be8-f2e0-4cf3-9823-80c20d1a436e","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"f6af654a-341d-45a8-a1a4-c2d17e5ea072","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"b605ddc1-1408-4956-864f-c602df6f550a","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"top":{"field":"Sales"},"width":{"value":0.2},"x":{"field":"day"}},"id":"25d28579-4ce2-4d3e-8946-c6e0500c573c","type":"VBar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"61100931-0c81-49dd-b38e-b0ba2ad2b715","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":"YEARLY SALES"},"id":"f6ba763a-1582-4691-8c88-658157e6752c","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"callback":{"id":"46a732ae-b9c4-4617-b4fe-831f344608ec","type":"CustomJS"},"end":12,"start":1,"title":"Month","value":1},"id":"eb513edf-4b54-4590-9b7b-d4cc1f60420c","type":"Slider"},{"attributes":{},"id":"f24d2be8-f2e0-4cf3-9823-80c20d1a436e","type":"Selection"}],"root_ids":["0a97fc7d-20ab-49fa-b18f-ca63fdc4d277"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"0.12.16"}}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var fn = function() {
              Bokeh.safely(function() {
                (function(root) {
                  function embed_document(root) {
                    
                  var docs_json = document.getElementById('59b3ceeb-f6e4-457f-8243-236ad4e4ecc6').textContent;
                  var render_items = [{"docid":"6e250d5c-2f75-4d15-9ea7-19bd720babe3","elementid":"1b4d2791-052d-4f87-b697-2703d126d006","modelid":"0a97fc7d-20ab-49fa-b18f-ca63fdc4d277"}];
                  root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
                
                  }
                  if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                    embed_document(root);
                  } else {
                    var attempts = 0;
                    var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                      if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        embed_document(root);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                      attempts++;
                      if (attempts > 100) {
                        console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing")
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                    }, 10, root)
                  }
                })(window);
              });
            };
            if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
            else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
          })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Aritesh, Thank you so much for yourtime. I am able to implement this logic. But, my sales data as per days is not correct. However, the data for month=1 is showing correctly. Data for rest of the months is incorrect. I guess, the loop function inside CustomJava script to read daily sales  is Incorrect, Can you please verify this logic. Once again, I am so thankful for your time.

Comment: Hi Aritesh, I did go through the code once again. I figured it out that, the old data in days dont replace. It stays same and new data is not being pushed. Loop seems to be correct. Do you have any idea to delete the days data before replacing it with new data ?Thanks in advance

Comment: THIS WORKED FOR ME WITH A LITTLE TWEAK. Inside CustomJs, rather referring to X and TOP, i referred to day and Sales

Comment: @trinathreddy, thats correct, I made the edit in answer

Comment: Hi aritesh, also have a small doubt. We need to integrate these plots on sahrepoint. Thats the reason , I am opting for CustomJs. I heard, using bokeh server wont allow us to integrate the plots on sharepoint. Is this correct ? Or, I will be more than happy to use native callback functions.

Comment: On Sharepoint, Bokeh server won't work, you will have to use js callbacks

Comment: Thank you aritesh. I have been working on Bokeh Multi Select. Have an issue in grabbing set of values and pass it to the plot. Please see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747006/bokeh-multi-select-widget-callback-not-working) here , whenever you get time. Thank You

Comment: @bigreddot  I have got a similar question for worldmap, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60838179/bokeh-update-map-tooltip-using-select-or-slider can you guys check?

Comment: @bigreddot I think there are a few issues with this solution in the current version of Bokeh (2.0.2). I've tried fixing it myself, unfortunately it seems that I cannot get it quite right in the JS code. I've suggested a couple of minor edits, however, could you be persuaded to help out fixing the rest? I'm very interested in the solution for this one.

Answer (score 0):

This CustomJs worked.

```
    callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=Overall, sc=Curr), code="""       
    var f = slider.value;
    sc.data['day'] = [];
    sc.data['ExtendedPrice'] = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= source.get_length(); i++){
      if (source.data['month'][i] == f){

        sc.data['day'].push(source.data['day'][i])
        sc.data['ExtendedPrice'].push(source.data['ExtendedPrice'][i])
      }
    }
    sc.change.emit();
""")
```

I appreciate your time aritesh. Thank you so much!