# Bokeh update map tooltip using select or slider

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh, bokehjs, pandas-bokeh

I am trying to update a worldmap tooltip using a slicer or dropdown select. I got following question which sorted the most of the stuff for a [Bokeh Slider custom JS callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689700/bokeh-slider-custom-js-callback)

```
import pandas as pd
import random
from datetime import timedelta

df = pd.DataFrame({'base' : ["2017-01-01" for t in range(10000)],
    'Date' : [random.randint(0, 1035) for t in range(10000)], 
                   'Sales' : [random.random() for t in range(10000)]})
df['base'] = pd.to_datetime(df['base'])
df["Date2"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["base"] + timedelta(days=x['Date']), axis=1)
df.drop(['base', 'Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.set_index('Date2', inplace=True)
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['year'] = df.index.year
df['day'] = df.index.day
df.head()

from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider,Select
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file

from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models import Slider, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.models.ranges import FactorRange
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, IndexFilter, BooleanFilter, HoverTool


source1=df.groupby(['year','month','day'], as_index = False).sum()
source = source1[source1['year']== 2017]
sourcex = source[source['month'] ==1]
Overall=ColumnDataSource(source)
Curr=ColumnDataSource(sourcex)
boolinit = source['month']==1
view = CDSView(source=Overall, filters=[BooleanFilter(boolinit)])
hover3 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('day', '@day'),('Sales','@{Sales}{0,0}')],
                   formatters = {'day': 'datetime','Sales': 'numeral'})

p =  figure(title='YEARLY SALES',  plot_width=600, plot_height=400, min_border=3,
tools = [hover3,'box_zoom','wheel_zoom', 'pan','reset'],  
toolbar_location="above")

r = p.vbar(x='day', top='Sales', width=0.2, color='#e8bc76', source=Curr)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Day'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_style = 'normal'
p.xaxis.axis_label_text_font_size = '12pt'



callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=Overall, sc=Curr), code="""       
        var f = select.value;
        sc.data['day'] = [];
        sc.data['Sales'] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= source.get_length(); i++){
          if (source.data['month'][i] == f){
            sc.data['day'].push(source.data['day'][i])
            sc.data['Sales'].push(source.data['Sales'][i])
          }
        }
        sc.change.emit();
    """)
select = Select(options=["1","2","3"], title="Month", callback=callback)
callback.args["select"] = select

layout = column(select, p)
#Display plot inline in Jupyter notebook
output_notebook()
output_file("Filterdata.html")
show(layout)
```

Now, I replicated the same for a worldmap as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
current_week = 4
shapefile = 'data/countries_110m/ne_110m_admin_0_countries.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(shapefile)[['ADMIN', 'ADM0_A3', 'geometry']]
gdf.columns = ['country', 'country_code', 'geometry']
gdf = gdf.drop(gdf.index[159])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['India','India'],
              'SalesGain':['10%','20%'],
                   'Week':[4,5],
                   'Color':[0.2,0.4]
             })

import json
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider,Select
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show, output_file
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, column
from bokeh.models import Slider, ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.core.properties import value
from bokeh.models.ranges import FactorRange
from bokeh.palettes import brewer
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, IndexFilter, BooleanFilter, HoverTool,GeoJSONDataSource, LinearColorMapper, ColorBar

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
output_file("worldmap.html")


merged = gdf.merge(df, left_on = 'country', right_on = 'Country', how = 'left')
merged_json = json.loads(merged.to_json())
json_data = json.dumps(merged_json)
geosource_all = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson =  json_data)

df_curr = df[df['Week']==current_week]
merged_curr = gdf.merge(df_curr, left_on = 'country', right_on = 'Country', how = 'left')
merged_json_curr = json.loads(merged_curr.to_json())
json_data_curr = json.dumps(merged_json_curr)
geosource_curr = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson =  json_data_curr)


# boolinit = merged['Week']!=current_week
boolinit = merged['Week']==current_week
view = CDSView(source=geosource_all, filters=[BooleanFilter(boolinit)])
hover3 = HoverTool(tooltips = [('Country', '@Country'),('Sales','@SalesGain')])

#Define a sequential multi-hue color palette.
palette = brewer['YlGnBu'][8]
#Reverse color order so that dark blue is highest value
palette = palette[::-1]
#Instantiate LinearColorMapper that linearly maps numbers in a range, into a sequence of colors. Input nan_color.
color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = palette, low = 0, high = 12, nan_color = '#d9d9d9')
#Define custom tick labels for color bar.
tick_labels = {'0': '0', '2':'2%',  '4':'4%',  '6':'6%', '8':'8%','10':'10%','12':'12%'}
#Create color bar. 
color_bar = ColorBar(color_mapper=color_mapper, label_standoff=6,width = 500, height = 20,
                     border_line_color=None,location = (0,0), orientation = 'horizontal', major_label_overrides = tick_labels)


#Create figure object.
p =  figure(title='Covid-19 Impact',  plot_width=900, plot_height=600, min_border=3,
            tools = [hover3,'box_zoom','wheel_zoom', 'pan','reset'],toolbar_location="above")

p.title.text_font_size = '20pt'
p.title.text_color = "darkblue"
p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None


#Add patch renderer to figure. 
p.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource_curr,fill_color = {'field' :'Color', 'transform' : color_mapper},
          line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)
p.add_layout(color_bar, 'below')


callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=geosource_all, sc=geosource_curr), code="""       
        var f = slider.value;
        sc.data['Country'] = [];
        sc.data['Week'] = [];
        sc.data['SalesGain'] = [];
        for (var i = 0; i <= source.get_length(); i++){
          if ((source.data['Week'][i] == f ) || (source.data['Country'][i] == null) ){
            sc.data['SalesGain'].push(source.data['SalesGain'][i])
            sc.data['Week'].push(source.data['Week'][i])
            sc.data['Country'].push(source.data['Country'][i])
          }
        }
        sc.change.emit();
    """)
# select = Select(options=["201951","201952","201953"], title="Week", callback=callback)
# callback.args["select"] = select
# layout = column(select, p)

slider = Slider(start=1, end=5, value=current_week, step=1, title="Month", callback=callback)
callback.args["slider"] = slider
layout = column(slider, p)

#Display plot inline in Jupyter notebook
output_notebook()

show(layout)
```

But in this case, as soon as I click on the slider, tooltip data vanish away. World map input file can be found here to smoothly run the code:
https://github.com/CrazyDaffodils/Interactive-Choropleth-Map-Using-Python/tree/master/bokeh-app/data

Answer (score 0):

A tooltip disappears after a small delay after you move your mouse off the glyph that has triggered it.

Right now, Bokeh doesn't have any built-in way of changing that behavior. There's an open issue for that with a workaround that you might be able to adapt to your needs: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/5724

Comment: In my case, tooltip data is not being updated for the map version, however bar chart is working perfectly fine.

Comment: @ManishSingla Ah, I see. The problem in your code is not with the tooltips. Because of your callback, you end up with a data source that has columns of different lengths. That's undefined behavior. In your JS console you should be able to see a warning about that.

Comment: An advice in advance - don't change data sources when you can. Just use `CDSView` and some filters.

Comment: Can you please share how to use the CDSView for the worldmap and why is it working in the bar?

Comment: The bar example works because it changes the whole data source - the columns in there stay the same length. I cannot really fix your example because I have no idea what you actually intended to do with the columns that you don't change. I can try to adapt the bar example to use `CDSView`s, if that helps.